# How to rotate circle in Direct2D in Visual C++ using pressed left mouse button?

Tags: visual-c++, vector-graphics, direct2d

I begin to use Direct2D and I'd like to know how to rotate circle in Direct2D in Win32 Visual C++ application with pressed left mouse button?
I'll be very thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a rotation transform to you render target using the ID2D1RenderTarget::SetTransform method and the D2D1::Matrix3x2F helper class. See [this MSDN topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff684172(v=vs.85).aspx) for a full example.

If you want to rotate it in response to a left mouse button click, you can handle a WM_LBUTTONDOWN message in your window procedure:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        // Code to re-draw the circle with a different rotation transform

    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I not need to rotate circle with single mouse click but I need to press LMB and holding it pressed down doing rotation of the circle with the mouse.

Comment: How to tie the mouse coordinates with the circle coordinates together in this last case?

Comment: OK, then you can handle WM_MOUSEMOVE instead, and check the lParam parameter within the window procedure, which contains the mouse cursor coordinates (see the MSDN docs for WM_MOUSEMOVE). Then call Matrix3x2F::Rotation with the angle of the x and y coordinates relative to the center of your circle. I'm not sure how to calculate the angle though. Maybe ask another question for that.

Comment: Thanks. And this approach is appropriate for not only rotation of circle but also for rotation of arc, or line, or rectangle, e.t.c?